# How to use LiveData in place of LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Earlier, to communicate between service and activity LocalBroadcastManager was used . But now it is deprecated and the official documentation suggests to use LiveData instead. So how to pass data from service to activity using LiveData ?

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. The alternative is to have your service update whatever data you need in your data repository, and also have your activity (potentially through a ViewModel) observe the same data. This avoids the Global/Singleton event buses and similar (which are terrible) and sends data in one-way. Is it better? "yes", is it annoying? Possibly.

Comment: The reason why it was deprecated besides the fact that it violates a lot of "principles" is that it's local, so you're broadcasting on a system designed to broadcast to the whole system (non-local broadcasts), so you are within the same process, and using Intents adds overhead (and intent limitations on its own). SO the idea is not to "just deprecate" the class, which you can still use if you want, but to change the paradigm of how you think about your inter-component communication.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Marconcini

Comment: @MartinMarconcini If the data my service generates is one way data which is not needed to be stored for sub-sequent runs, is there a way to avoid a repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good alternative would be to:

1. define the data you want read/write inside a Repository object as LiveData
2. make your activity observe that LiveData (or even better use a ViewModel between your Repo and Activity
   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
3. make your service call some Repository's saveXXX() or updateXXX() methods to update your data, and the activity will automatically get the updates !

You can also follow this Guide to a good app architecture
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide